# How to get JSON data from multiple URLS in ReactJS using search term in searchbox?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I want to get json data from multiple url's and display it on frontend. Following are the url's:

```
1) localhost:3000/api/getdata1

2) localhost:3000/api/getdata2

3) localhost:3000/api/getdata3
```

Instead of using .fetch() on each of the url's like below:

```
.fetch('localhost:3000/api/getdata1')

.fetch('localhost:3000/api/getdata2')

.fetch('localhost:3000/api/getdata3')
```

I am going to make use of promise but how can I pass the search term of my search box as a query to my api endpoint ? Is there more efficient way or better way to do this (In ReactJS)-> Take search term from search box and then inject that search term inside api endpoint using template string feature of ES6.

```
const dataurls = [
    'localhost:3000/api/getdata1/q={searchterm}',
    'localhost:3000/api/getdata2/q={searchterm}',
    'localhost:3000/api/getdata3/q={searchterm}'
];
const promisedurl = dataurls.map(httpGet);

Promise.all(promisedurls)
.then(data=> {
    for (const d of data) {
        console.log(d);
    }
})
.catch(reason => {
    // Receives first rejection among the Promises
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand the problem correctly, one way of doing this could be

```
const dataUrls = [
    'localhost:3000/api/getdata1',
    'localhost:3000/api/getdata2',
    'localhost:3000/api/getdata3'
];

const dataRequests = dataUrls.map((apiEndpoint) => fetch(`${apiEndpoint}/q=${searchTerm}`));

Promise.all(dataRequests)
.then((data) => {
    for (const d of data) {
        console.log(d);
    }
})
.catch(reason => {
    // Receives first rejection among the Promises
});
```

Although this is not specific to `react` per say, this should get the job done.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`template literal`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to add your `searchterm` to your url.

```js
const searchterm = 'abc';
const dataurls = [
    `localhost:3000/api/getdata1/q=${searchterm}`,
    `localhost:3000/api/getdata2/q=${searchterm}`,
    `localhost:3000/api/getdata3/q=${searchterm}`
];
console.log(dataurls);
```